# My question is closed for being unclear. I don't think it is. Could it be reopened?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have asked the following question on Stack Overflow:
[How to encode stream of bits (not bytes) in Python - is any simple module for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161320/how-to-encode-stream-of-bits-not-bytes-in-python-is-any-simple-module-for-it)

It was closed for being unclear, but I don't see how it is. Could it be reopened?

BTW: **How it possible** that people gives **correct very clear answers** on *unclear question* :)

Comment: Questions with up voted answers cannot be deleted; please don't self-vandalise the post

Comment: It is already vandalized by others. Someone change content to prove something untrue :)

Comment: Time to finish contribution to Stackoverflow. Today I am very disappointed by StackOverflow moderation – I do not want use StackOverflow (I was using 2 years) – time to find alternatives – I am not slave – I do not deserve on such treat after many contributions – one of moderators insulted me seriously.

Read it and see why: http://goo.gl/VHTLim, http://goo.gl/974pA7, http://goo.gl/kjscOU

Comment: I'm somewhat unclear as to which part was insulting. Regardless, that is your choice

Comment: You will not read it since he delete all comments 5 times and not respond to any question. "You confirm that dragonx comment is off-topic and you mark my question because of this comment as off-topic too"

Comment: @RichardTingle As you see I was punish with some kind of "ban" and all bad things was put on me because some gang member put off-topic comment on my question - I am become guilt of someone stupid off-topic comments - I am not god to control all people comments they should know it ... :) I am only asked about moderation :)

Comment: I'm not here to second guess a moderator's decision; I would however ask how you responded to that 'off topic comment'. If you have a specific complaint you should direct your email [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) to contact Stack Exchange directly; I would suggest you focus on exactly what the problem was in as short a message as possible

Comment: I try it (I sent already) maybe StakOverflou will not want die because some moderator what to kill its spirit and insult users :) He is easy to insult but not ready to apologize I think.

Comment: Actually, 'unclear what you're asking' is a synonyme for 'you have posted your requirements instead of specific problem you've found implementing them'. It's, in my opinion, bad decision that wreaks chaos and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 19):

Let's look at your question. It starts out with

> I want encode and decode ...

Great, that's what you want. Now reading further, besides some unclear parts regarding your precise objective, I can't help but wonder what the problem is. What is your question? How far have you gotten towards what you want? What is missing? Why can't you create it? Or did you do so but got stuck somewhere?

You want something, sure. But that is not a question it itself. It can at most be translated into a request. And if that is what you're going for, you don't have a question.

> How it possible that people gives correct very clear answers on unclear (false) question?

That really signals a couple of things. You seem to think that anything that can be answered, is a proper question for Stack Overflow. It isn't. I bet you I can fulfil my clients' requests, if they tell me what they want to have in the end. And so can some of the great users of the site write code for you that does what you want it to do. (I think they really shouldn't, but some are willing to go beyond what can be expected from them) That is not where things become unclear.

The general idea here would be that we help you to **solve your own problem**. That is, **you do the work, we assist**. So make it very clear where you are in this process and how we can help you out, without us having to do the actual work for you.

If you clarify the question with that in mind, and address some of the concerns regarding what exactly you want to achieve, then I'm pretty sure your question would be no longer unclear.

If you are however not looking to solve your own problems, writing your own code, then Stack Overflow might not be the place for it.

Comment: _"So make it very clear where you are in this process and how we can help you out"_... At the moment the question is basically "I have 41 things at most but it could be more and I want to do the thing and the other thing", I think the close reason was fair.

Comment: Absolutely @benisuǝqbackwards. I'm actually rather surprised at the level of help that was still given.

Comment: @bart Do you think that I do not what I want to ask and should ask different question with more open scope. I asked valid question more context will not help since want convert **variable limited list of bits** into for example **number** to store or interchange. You are right that some people can have problem with asking question - true is also that some is not all.

Comment: Tell me why answer was clear and question is not clear that is nonsense :)

Comment: I have already told you so. You are not asking a question. You're making a request at most. A request to solve your problems for you. And while user can and have taken to that request, that does not mean that you've asked a question appropriate for the site. You have to solve your own problems, perhaps with our help. If you want people to do your work for you, that's fine, but then pay them and don't ask that on SO.

Comment: *"Tell me why answer was clear and question is not clear that is nonsense"* One person out of the scores who looked at the question was able---after reading an extensive comment thread---to guess what the question might be and write you an answer. All that proves is that Stack Overflow is inhabited by smart people.

Comment: @dmckee Smart people can behave stupid that is no matter - history of world shows that many times. I just want to say that it is invalid moderation and should be corrected/change.

Comment: BTW Is Forest Gump was smart or behave smart - thanks for answer :)

Comment: Forrest Gump was a movie character which will not help you towards your goal of reopening your question. Perhaps it's smarter to consider some of the advice and address the concerns of several users. That will be more productive than immediately trying to deny or refute anything you've been told so far.

Comment: This reminds me when people go to the doctor and *don't tell* the whole picture. The poor doc *has to guess* based on s/his previous experience what is *truly going on*. @Chameleon, do you mean Stack Forest or Gump Overflow? :)

Comment: @brasofilo Good remark about doctor with sense of humor :) Sometime you  can tell doctor/moderator all but he/she not distinct right illness and can kill you by stupidity using wrong therapy :) Good doctor will not allow you to be unclear :) I think all is spoken nothing will happen in moderation of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 12):

If five people have voted to close the question because it is unclear, then perhaps it is clear for you, but not for other people reading your question.

If you feel that your question should be reopened, click on the "reopen" link: you have the privilege to cast close/reopen votes on your own questions. Note that after you have voted to reopen, you need four other votes to reopen (from other users) before your question gets reopened.

Comment: You think is five people is wrong that mean that it is become true - that is true for propaganda but not works in programming since not benefit from propaganda in programming?

Comment: @Chameleon:  What?

Comment: @Makoto What do you mean what?

Comment: I mean, "I'm quite confused by your statement.  I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at with it.  I do not see how your analogy to propaganda makes sense in this context.  I do not understand your remark."

Comment: @Makoto I am not understand many things but it not mean that they are no meaning :) Propaganda is art of lie/false people to convince them to own agenda - whatever it can not change fact that anyone can answer clearly unclear question, am I right? Some is if more poeple belive something become fact :)

Comment: @Makoto - If you read Cham's first comment aloud, it makes for entertaining stuff. Jussst saying

Comment: @Adel Completly wrong grammar should be: Do you think that if five people is wrong that it makes true (As mean that more people repeating lie it can become true).

Comment: @Chameleon - I will admit that sometimes 5 people can be wrong. Unfortunately the mental taxation needed for the 1st close vote is far more than the 3rd close vote. People tend to "pile-on" , and that behavior has been discussed. just difficult to fix it, I think

Comment: @Chameleon - Overall, your grammar & English is fine. it's actually a bit endearing in its tone. We all can improve of course

Comment: @adel It is constructive comment people tend to behave like others so it is high probability that they no be arbitrary if see other opinions - see **this whole discussion it is ruled by this law clear**.

Comment: @Chameleon: Five people can be wrong, but if 5 **other** people notice that there's nothing wrong with your question, then they can vote to reopen (and your question is now reopened). That's the purpose of voting to reopen.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Tell me what is your level of expertise in Python and algorithms - basic, medium, advanced, pro? Should I trust you depend on level of expertise or on number of words?

Comment: @Chameleon: I don't have expertise in Python. I'm telling what *other* people (who have expertise) might think. My comment doesn't even have to do with Python, just with voting to close/reopen.

Comment: @ProgramFOX As you should know you can not judge advanced Python question without Python expertise if it clear or not. You can not judge anything without expertise/experience that is my point of view - so it is not matter how may people but what was their competence. I am against "burning witches" it is not matter of my arrogance it is rational. I can judge who do not know Python/Programming easily.

Comment: @Chameleon: If a Python question is clear, then every programmer (even a non-Python programmer) should be able to understand your question. They won't understand your code, but the question should be understandable for everyone.

Comment: @ProgramFOX You are in big mistake - I can prove it easily - "every programmer should understand clear question" - since I am very good Python programmer and **do not understand** some Python questions **that is false**. I also **do not understand "Haskell" and "Schema"** - no matter that I know PHP, Python, Yaml, C#, C++, Java, Modula, Eiffel, Perl, ... and many more language what is rare!!! :):):) To answer Python question you need understand domain and has Python expertise no be only programmer - **that is true**.

Comment: @Chameleon: But after searching (in Google for example) for "Haskell" or "Schema", and after learning what they mean, you'll be able to understand the question.

Comment: @ProgramFOX well, you're currently wrong. The people are voting to close as unclear because question doesn't show enough understanding, or doesn't provide attempted solution, or doesn't fall under SSCCE principe.

Comment: @ŁukaszL.: That's true, but I wrote this answer *before* the 'minimal understanding' reason was removed. Should I update my answer, or do you think that's not necessary?

Answer (score 5):

Some of this has been covered in other answers, but I wanted to summarize some of the StackOverflow "features" you've run into:

- The reason that is presented to you for why a question is closed, is *not* necessarily the reason that everyone who voted to close it gave for closing it. I think it's the "most frequently" given reason, but I'm not sure (and I'm not sure what happens in the event of a tie).
- Even if everyone who voted to close it gave the same reason, the reason may have little to do with why it was closed, because the text that closers have to choose from is essentially "fixed" and in some case only tortuously related to the "internal meaning" of the close choices
- If you ask why a question is closed on MSO, you may get answers that are completely unrelated to why the people who voted to close actually voted to close it. That's because anyone who didn't vote to close has no idea what or why those who *did* vote to close voted.
- There are lots of questions which clearly do not meet StackOverflow criteria for which you will get answers that are completely acceptable to you. You can't use "answer quality from your perspective" as a means to evaluate "question quality from StackOverflow perspective"
- Since "question clarity" is evaluated in the context of the English language, it's harder for those not fluent in English to ask clear questions, let alone evaluate question clarity
- "Enforcement" of StackOverflow criteria is so sporadic and uneven as to be essentially arbitrary, so you can't look at the disposition of one question and assume that a similar question will be similarly treated.
- Specifically, questions of the form "How do you code x?" may be perfectly clear and there are hundreds of such questions asked and answered every day on StackOverflow. However, many people in the StackOverflow community feel strongly that such questions are inappropriate, should not be answered and will vote to close them. However, for reasons noted above, you will not see that given as a close reason.
- Last but not least, downvotes on Meta Stack Overflow are notoriously cast against questions for which the poster is perceived as displaying an "attitude" (e.g. indignation, entitlement, anger, righteousness). As noted above, I cannot in any way be sure of the extent to which that has taken place here, but that would be my suspicion.

Comment: Your comments are very good and constructive. We have as result very random moderation and what I mean by high quality answer not fits moderation rules which can not be arbitrary or was not arbitrary.

Comment: @Chameleon I don't understand the last part of your comment, but in the case of this question, there was no "moderation" involved (i.e. no action by moderators) that I am aware of.  The "closing process" is performed by the community and that process is what I have characterized as largely arbitrary.

Comment: I mean "moderation" as moderation effect of all action not as "moderation" is only done by moderator. Whatever in this case moderators was involved in "moderation" too.

Comment: Are you referring to those who voted to close? If so, I didn't recognize any of the names as moderators. In any event, I'm still confused by your comment about arbitrariness. Ultimately, this comes down to the collective behavior of a few individuals out of a population of literally millions. That's never going to be very predictable.

Comment: I referring to this thread as you recognized. I am referring to this case and common behavior on StackOverflow similar to "burning witch". I am against "automatic labeling people" since it leads to "burning witch" without reason. Such behavior is very frequent - if you asked more complex question there is higher chance some idiotic behavior will happen :) It looks that people want keep lower level of StackOverflow the same behavior is on some Wikipedias (it depend on language) :)